# How to retrieve data from MongoDB databse using specific date range and aggregation in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, microservices, aggregation

I am working on a spring boot project and using MongoDB as my database.

There is studentDB database which contains a student document and that documents contain the following fields:

_id , student_name, attend_lecture, iso_dom, iso_dow, iso_month, iso_year, iso_week".

student document

```
   _id             Object
   student_name    String
   attend_lecture  int
   iso_dom         int    date of the month ("1" January 2015)
   iso_dow         int    day of the week (Friday)
   iso_month       int    the month (1 stand for January)
   iso_year        int    year (2015)
   iso_week        int    week number (1)
```

Here I am trying to retrieve how many students attended lectures in the date range between 12 January 2015 to 13 March 2015?

**Methods I have Tried:**

1. I used the aggregation with less than and greater than clause in MongoDB.
2. I also used the date of the part clause while I retrieved all the dates between 12 January 2015 to 13 March 2015.

**Problem:**
Is there any feasible way to retrieve how many students attended lectures in the date range between 12 January 2015 to 13 March 2015?

**Example:**

student document

```
  "_id":"5c1639b3a1b32bb04547137f",

  "student_name":"MR. Rahul"

  "iso_dom":12,

  "iso_dow":3,

  "iso_month":1,

  "iso_week":12,

  "isp_year":2018,

  "attend_lecture":5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert new key date which gives an option to select documents between two dates and using the aggregate function retrieve how many students attended lectures in the date range between 12 January 2015 to 13 March 2015.